# Multiply Text Field Error?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, calculator

I want to multiply a text field by a multiplier, but I keep getting the error below. Can anyone help? Using Swift.

```
Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Double'


    var Number1 = Int(weight.text!)
    let lidocainemult = (1.5)

 var lidoresult = Number1 * lidocainemult


    lidocaine.text = NSString(format:"%d",lidoresult)as String;
```

Comment: You are trying to multiply optional integer and a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to convert your variables into the same type first. Here `Double` would make the most sense, since there would be no loss of information (unlike rounding to produce an `Int`!).

```
var Number1 = Double(weight.text!)
let lidocainemult = (1.5)
var lidoresult = Number1 * lidocainemult
lidocaine.text = NSString(format:"%d",lidoresult)as String;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must convert `Number1` to a `Double`, the operands must be of same type.

```
var Number1 = Double(weight.text!)
```